# Get maximal values from several records with Lambda expression

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, c#-6.0

```
public class MySoft
{
    public string SoftName { get; set; }
    public int Version { get; set; }
    public decimal Price { get; set; }

}
```

As datas I have list of "MySoft" (softname, version, price):

```
SoftA   1   25
SoftB   1   35
SoftB   2   12
SoftB   3   24
SoftA   2   14
```

I'd like get keep the name, price and version with the highest version.

The result should be :

```
SoftA 2 14
SoftB 3 24
```

Do you have an idea ?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this too,

```
 var result = softwares.GroupBy(item => item.SoftName)
        .Select(grp => grp.Aggregate((max, cur) =>
                             (max == null || cur.Version > max.Version) ? cur : max));
```

**[Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/EwmHKe)**

Answer (score 2):

Just group by the name, then order each group on the Version and take the last one.

```
var results = list.GroupBy(x => x.SoftName)
    .Select(g => g.OrderBy(x => x.Version).Last());
```